# Can the probability of a continuous random variable over a range of values be 0?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The probability of a continuous random variable for a specific value is always 0. But can a range of values in a continuous random variable over a range of values be 0?

Answer (score 2):

A random variable that is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ has probability $0$ of being in the interval $[2, 3]$.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Take the exponential random variable for example, it has probability 0 of being in $(-\infty,0)$